# How to get array from form correctly?

Tags: php, laravel

I have little issue with my form,

I want to insert into two tables data, and one is in array and should be use foreach loop to insert data to database.

Im trying to insert data like

```
|name | address | description | is_featured | status |
```

to `branch` table. And this array thing i try to insert into `booking_times` table

```
|booking_name | start_time | end_time | multiple_booking | max_booking | status |
```

At the moment my array gives this array and this isnt right array looking:

```
array(40) { 
    [0]=> array(1) { 
            [\"status\"]=> string(2) \"on\" 
        } 
    [1]=> array(1) { 
            [\"status\"]=> string(2) \"on\" 
        } 
    [2]=> array(1) { 
            [\"status\"]=> string(2) \"on\" 
        } 
    [3]=> array(1) { 
            [\"status\"]=> string(2) \"on\" 
        } 
    [4]=> array(1) { 
            [\"status\"]=> string(2) \"on\" 
        } 
    [5]=> array(1) { 
            [\"booking_name\"]=> string(6) \"Monday\" 
        } 
    [6]=> array(1) { 
            [\"start_time\"]=> string(8) \"08:00 AM\" 
        } 
    [7]=> array(1) { 
            [\"end_time\"]=> string(8) \"06:00 PM\" 
        } 
    [8]=> array(1) { 
            [\"multiple_booking\"]=> string(3) \"yes\" 
        } 
    [9]=> array(1) { 
            [\"max_booking\"]=> string(1) \"0\" 
        } 
    [10]=> array(1) { 
            [\"booking_name\"]=> string(7) \"Tuesday\" 
        } 
    [11]=> array(1) { 
            [\"start_time\"]=> string(8) \"08:00 AM\" 
        } 
    [12]=> array(1) { 
        [\"end_time\"]=> string(8) \"06:00 PM\" } [13]=> array(1) { [\"multiple_booking\"]=> string(3) \"yes\" } [14]=> array(1) { [\"max_booking\"]=> string(1) \"0\" } [15]=> array(1) { [\"booking_name\"]=> string(9) \"Wednesday\" } [16]=> array(1) { [\"start_time\"]=> string(8) \"08:00 AM\" } [17]=> array(1) { [\"end_time\"]=> string(8) \"06:00 PM\" } [18]=> array(1) { [\"multiple_booking\"]=> string(3) \"yes\" } [19]=> array(1) { [\"max_booking\"]=> string(1) \"0\" } [20]=> array(1) { [\"booking_name\"]=> string(8) \"Thursday\" } [21]=> array(1) { [\"start_time\"]=> string(8) \"08:00 AM\" } [22]=> array(1) { [\"end_time\"]=> string(8) \"06:00 PM\" } [23]=> array(1) { [\"multiple_booking\"]=> string(3) \"yes\" } [24]=> array(1) { [\"max_booking\"]=> string(1) \"0\" } [25]=> array(1) { [\"booking_name\"]=> string(6) \"Friday\" } [26]=> array(1) { [\"start_time\"]=> string(8) \"08:00 AM\" } [27]=> array(1) { [\"end_time\"]=> string(8) \"06:00 PM\" } [28]=> array(1) { [\"multiple_booking\"]=> string(3) \"yes\" } [29]=> array(1) { [\"max_booking\"]=> string(1) \"0\" } [30]=> array(1) { [\"booking_name\"]=> string(8) \"Saturday\" } [31]=> array(1) { [\"start_time\"]=> string(8) \"08:00 AM\" } [32]=> array(1) { [\"end_time\"]=> string(8) \"06:00 PM\" } [33]=> array(1) { [\"multiple_booking\"]=> string(3) \"yes\" } [34]=> array(1) { [\"max_booking\"]=> string(1) \"0\" } [35]=> array(1) { [\"booking_name\"]=> string(6) \"Sunday\" } [36]=> array(1) { [\"start_time\"]=> string(8) \"08:00 AM\" } [37]=> array(1) { [\"end_time\"]=> string(8) \"06:00 PM\" } [38]=> array(1) { [\"multiple_booking\"]=> string(3) \"yes\" } [39]=> array(1) { [\"max_booking\"]=> string(1) \"0\" } }
```

correct way should `booking_times` array should look like this:

```
[
    ["booking_name" => "Monday", "start_time" => "08:00 AM", "end_time" => "06:00 PM", "multiple_booking" => "yes", "max_booking" => 0, "status" => "on"],
    ["booking_name" => "Tuesday", "start_time" => "08:00 AM", "end_time" => "06:00 PM", "multiple_booking" => "yes", "max_booking" => 0, "status" => "on"],
    ["booking_name" => "Wednesday", "start_time" => "08:00 AM", "end_time" => "06:00 PM", "multiple_booking" => "yes", "max_booking" => 0, "status" => "on"],
    ....
]
```

And my form look like this:
https://pastebin.com/MEReGBRb

Comment: And what's your question about this? What keeps you from adjusting the form values? Could you show the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an index number for each `bookingTime` input set. Like this:

```html
<div class="col-md-1">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="bookingTime[0][booking_name]" value="Sunday" hidden>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bookingTime[0][start_time]" value="08:00 AM">
</div>


<div class="col-md-1">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="bookingTime[1][booking_name]" value="Sunday" hidden>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bookingTime[1][start_time]" value="08:00 AM">
</div>
```

if you are using blade `@foreach` you can use laravel's `$loop` variable as index. Like this:

```html
@foreach($items as $item)
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="bookingTime[{{ $loop->index }}][booking_name]" value="Sunday" hidden>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bookingTime[{{ $loop->index }}][start_time]" value="08:00 AM">
  </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: in create blade you use foreach loop to insert data to table? What would be $items then.. it can't be empty.  So I have to insert manually `bookingTime[0][start_time], bookingTime[1][start_time]...` I know I have 7 days in week and I have to insert 7 rows to table `booking_times`

Comment: Maybe possible use counting loop 0 to 6 so it would loop me 7 input forms like you tried?

Comment: Yes easy way was just manyally add index numbers and now array is looking good. Thank you.